# Find a non-principal ideal (if there exists any) in the rings Z[x], Q[x], Q[x, y]

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

I know that $Q$ is a field, which makes $Q[x]$ a PID, which means there are none.

I'm having trouble with the notation for ideal generators, and i know the $Z[x]$ has to do with something that looks like $(2,x)$. Could someone explain this notation to me and also the general outlines of solving these problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example $(2,X)$ is a good one. It means the ideal generated by $2$ and $X$. You can think of this vaguely like a subspace of a vector space.

Explicitly
$(2,X) = \{ 2 p + X q \colon p, q \in \mathbb{Z}[X]\}$.

By construction it is an ideal. You need to show it is not generated by a single element. 
Assume a generator $g$. Then $g \mid 2$ and $g \mid X$. However, the only elements that do this are $1$ and $-1$. So the ideal generated by $g$ is the full ring, and thus $(2,X)$ would be the full ring. This is however not the case. (Prove it.)

For $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$, consider $(X,Y)$ and do roughly the same thing.

Both examples fall under the strategy: pick an element $f$ that has no nontrivial divisors and try to find another element $h$ that has no nontrivial divisors either and such that $(f,h)$ is not the full ring.

Comment: So by the ideal generated by 2 and x you mean the set of all sums and products of multiples of 2 and x? And then the question becomes proving that they have no common factor?

Comment: For the first, yes. More generally if you have a (commutative) ring $R$ than the ideal generated by elements $a_1, \dots,a_n$ is equal to the set of all "linear combinations" $r_1a_1 + \dots \dots r_na_n$ with $r_i \in R$. This might even be the definition, depending on how one sets things up.  For the second, also yes. Note that if an ideal is principal, then each element in it must be a multiple of one particular element, the generator $g$. In particular the generator must divide each element in the ideal.

Comment: Then in the  ℚ(X,Y) question, does the answer come from the fact that there is no number other than ±1 that divides x and y? And the reason ±1 is unsuitable as an ideal generator is that it generates the whole ring?

Comment: Yes, this is the reason. To be precise, in Q[X,Y] as opposed to Z[X,Y] it is not only 1, and -1 that divides X and Y but any nonzero  rational number. The conclusion is however the same. Also, let me correct a slopiness on my side. One should be careful to always write Q[X,Y] not usual parenthesis since Q(X,Y) means something else, namely rational functions.

Comment: Could you just explain further as to how any nonzero rational number divides X and Y and how a non zero rational number generates the whole ring?

Comment: Is it that if a/b generates the ideal, then taking b/a an element of Q, ab/ba=1 is an element of the ideal, so 1Q=Q is contained in (a/b) and (a/b)=q?

Comment: To say that $d$ divides $m$ in some ring $R$ means that there exists an $c$ such that $dc=m$. Let $q$ be a nonzero rational number. Let us check if $q$ divides $X$ in $Q[x,Y]$. We need to find some $r$  in $Q[X,Y]$ such that $qr= x$. We pick $r= q^{-1}X$. This works since $q^{-1}X$ is an element of $Q[X,Y]$. Note the distinction here to the situation for $Z[X]$. There we cannot just consider  $q^{-1}X$ since $q^{-1}$ will not be in Z even if $q$ was in Z, only for $q= \pm 1$ this works there. For your second comment: yes you can argue roughly like this. But it is better to replace Q by Q[X,Y]

Comment: Thats great, thank you so much

Comment: Glad I could help. :-)